# Passing data from Controller1 to Controller2 - Laravel8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am working on an enrolment system for dance studios.
I need to pull data from other database table like 'rooms', 'teachers', and 'courses' to assign into a class (not PHP class). Problem is Laravel can't detect the Controller assigned for $rooms and same to others. I have been stuck for weeks. Ideas will be much appreciated. Or let me know what documentation should I read.

Objective: I want to pass information about rooms to classes.

Here's my code:

classes/create (blade template)

```
<select>
 @if (count($rooms) > 0)
  @foreach ($rooms as $room)
   <option value="{{$room->id}}">{{$room->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
 @else
  <option value="">No rooms available</option>
 @endif                                                
</select>
```

ClassesController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Classes;
use DB;

class ClassesController extends Controller
{

    public function create()
    {
        return view('classes.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'class_name' => 'required',
            'class_course' => 'required',
            'class_start_date' => 'required',
            'class_end_date' => 'required',
            'class_start_time' => 'required',
            'class_end_time' => 'required',
            'class_teacher' => 'required',
            'class_room' => 'required',
        ]);
   
        //create new Class
        $classes = new Classes;
        $classes->class_name = $request->input('class_name');
        $classes->course_name = $request->input('class_course');
        $classes->start_date = $request->input('class_start_date');
        $classes->end_date = $request->input('class_end_date');
        $classes->start_time = $request->input('class_start_time');
        $classes->end_time = $request->input('class_end_time');
        $classes->teacher = $request->input('class_teacher');
        $classes->room = $request->input('class_room'); //**it should capture here**
        $classes->save();     

        return redirect('/classes')->with('success', 'New class created.');
    }
```

RoomsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Rooms;
use DB;

class RoomsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    
    public function index()
    {
        $rooms = Rooms::orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(10);
        return view('rooms.index')->with('rooms', $rooms);
    }
```

Technically, I need to pass a data from RoomsController to ClassesController.
I am using Laravel 8.

Please be patient with me, I am new to Laravel.

Thanks guys!

UPDATE: So I solved it.
Thanks for everyone who tried to answer! I appreciate your effort. However, I have managed to solve the issue above.

I just need to create a separate Controller that collects the data from other Controllers. Then route it like the way I route the other Controllers. That simple.

CreateClassController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Classes;
use App\Models\Rooms;
use DB;

class CreateClassController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $rooms = Rooms::all();
        return view('classes.create')->with('rooms', $rooms); 
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('/classes/create', controller: \App\Http\Controllers\CreateClassController::class);
```

There might be a more sophisticated approach but for now this works.

Thanks all!

Comment: what data do you want to pass?

Comment: The information about rooms. I want to get data about rooms to select which one to assign into a class and save to database.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel follows MVC architecture... so passing data directly from one controller to other wont work (as far as i know, could be wrong).
In rooms controller, add
`return view('view_name',['data'=>data]);`
in web.php, define a route name with controller class name (that of classess controller)
`Route::get('view_name',[classesController::class,'store'],function() {} );`